# Spark streaming with predefined ordering

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-spark-2.0

I have two streaming dataframes - `firstDataFrame` and `secondDataframe`. I want to stream firstDataframe completely. And if the first streaming finishes successfully, only then i would like to stream the other dataframe

For example, in the below code, I would like the first streaming action to execute completely and only then the second to begin

```
firstDataframe.writeStream.format("console").start 
secondDataframe.writeStream.format("console").start
```

Spark follows FIFO job scheduling by default. This means it would give priority to the first streaming job. However, if the first streaming job does not require all the available resources, it would start the second streaming job in parallel. I essentially want to avoid this parallelism. Is there a way to do this?

Reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application

Comment: hi @riteshkasat did you find a solution for this one?

Comment: i think one solution is to run two separate spark jobs one after another. Refer this link: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/orchestrate-apache-spark-applications-using-aws-step-functions-and-apache-livy/